# installing python interface

Tags: installation, python

I tried to install the Python interface to the Redis key-value store.

https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

I got the following error:

```
[shantanu@server andymccurdy-redis-py-60e3be5]$  python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in ?
    from redis import __version__
  File "/home/shantanu/andymccurdy-redis-py-60e3be5/redis/__init__.py", line 1, in ?
    from redis.client import Redis, StrictRedis
  File "/home/shantanu/andymccurdy-redis-py-60e3be5/redis/client.py", line 238
    with self.pipeline(True, shard_hint) as pipe:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

pip and easy_install did not work.

Comment: Which Python version are you running `python -V`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the python version >=2.5 or try using an older version of redis-py for your python version.